# Compile C on single machine and use it on cluster

Tags: c, compilation, cluster-computing

I'm a newby in C and it's the first time that I've to run a program on cluster and I've an (embarrassing) question.

The question is can I compile my C code on my machine and use it later on the cluster?

Both OS are Linux based. My pc is equipped with an i5 (Kaby Lake) while the cluster is equipped with Intel Skylake processors.

I've tried Googling the question but I've received unsatisfactory answers

Comment: You have to build a cluster version, for example with "openmp". But with most multi-processing frameworks you can also run it locally for testing purposes.

Comment: The code was designed with OpenMPI and tested, but now I should do some scaling test on a greater number of cores

Comment: Yes, you can compile it locally and run it on the cluster, as long as the same ISA is used (which is the case here). OpenMPI is well documented. Perhaps this may help you: https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=running

Comment: You'd have to be careful about using optimisations like `-march=native` which can make a massive performance difference but could prevent code compiled on your PC from running, or achieving its best performance on your cluster.

Comment: You probably can, but I don't know why you would need to. Unless your code is incredibly huge, it will probably be just as simple to recompile it on the cluster before running it there.  This will also avoid possible issues such as different shared library versions.

Comment: A new problem arise, I use some shared library that are not present on the cluster. What can I do? I could enforce static linking while compiling?